# alerting double encoded character

Tags: javascript, encoding

I'm trying to alert document.cookie when the dot is double encoded, but it doesn't work.
here's my code:

```
<script>alert(unescape(document%252Ecookie))</script>
```

How can i make it work using double encoding on the dot?
Thanks.

Comment: how about double decoding

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do? unescape works on strings. document%252Ecookie is not a string. please elaborate the problem

Comment: @Musa i tired unescape(unescape(, didn't work. to Reason, please don't waste my time, i said in clear detail what i wanted to do and that is to alert document.cookie when the dot is double encoded.

Comment: Like this http://jsfiddle.net/aqwdN/

Answer (score 0):

No idea what you are trying to do really, but here are some clarifications:

`unescape()` works on strings. it takes a string and returns another string. `document%252Ecookie` is not a string, so you cannot use `unescape()` on it.

To use unescape, put quotes around `"document%252Ecookie"`

`unescape(unescape("document%252Ecookie"))` will give you the string `"document.cookie"` (remember, unescape goes from strings to strings). If you alert this you will have an alert box saying `"document.cookie"`, which is probably not what you are looking for. To get the contents of `document.cookie` you can use `eval()`. It takes a string and evaluates the contents of it.

So to do what you want to do you would type:

```
alert(eval(unescape(unescape("document%252Ecookie"))))
```

No idea of why you would want to do this, but this is how it can be done. I want to point out that this code is pretty stupid, but hopefully I've made some things more clear to you.